# Could not load file or assembly 'Moxiecode.TinyMCE' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, tinymce

We keep getting this bug intermittently and recycling the app pool fixes it for sometime but then it comes back again. Has someone narrowed down the cause for this issue and found a permanent fix?

Also this happens only on production machines and not on dev or staging.

The web config has both entries as shown below:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="TinyMCE" type="Moxiecode.TinyMCE.ConfigHandler,Moxiecode.TinyMCE" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
```

---

```
    <TinyMCE installPath="Include/JavaScript/tiny_mce" mode="src">
        <!-- Default settings for all TinyMCE instances -->
        <globalSettings>
            <add key="relative_urls" value="false"/>
        </globalSettings>
        <!-- Compressor specific settings -->
        <gzipCompressor enabled="yes" noCompression="yes" diskCache="no" cachePath="c:\temp" expiresOffset="10d"/>
    </TinyMCE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning out "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files"? I know that recycling the app pool is still necessary here to release locks on the temporary files, but it's possible you have a corrupted dynamically compiled file in temp that refuses to die.

Comment: I haven't tried cleaning it out yet, but I think that may solve it for this particular instance, not sure if this stops it from happening again? (I say this cuz we had this issue couple of weeks back and everything was ok and it happened again yesterday)